# When does your pokemon get CP at a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

I went to a friendly gym and battled the lowest player and won multiple times, enough to up the gym level and leave my Ratticate there.  However his CP is still 313.  I thought the purpose of friendly fighting was to increase CP for your pokemon.  What am I missing?

Comment: Friendly matches increase arena prestige/level, that's the sole purpose of them. This helps keeping the arena defended against enemies.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Pokemon don't gain CP at a gym. Successfully training at a gym raises only that gym's "prestige," and consequentially, the gym's level.

The only way to increase the CP of your Pokemon is by using Stardust to power them up or evolve them.

The purpose of a [gym](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Gyms) is to put a Pokemon on it to defend it which can earn you 10 gold coins each (max 100) per 21 hours. You can collect them in the shop at the right top. This can be done straight after or you can wait.

Comment: not only the leader gets the reward, everyone with a Pokémon in the gym gets it

Comment: Do you have to hold the Gym for 21hours to get the reward? or will you get a cut for how long you've hold it?

Comment: @Taacoo You can claim the reward immediately after capturing a gym.(you do not have to hold it more than a few seconds). However, that will disable defender bonus claiming for 21 hours, so if you manage capture a second gym, you have to wait 21 hours to claim defender bonus. Hence, if you think you'll be able to control multiple gyms, you should capture as many as possible before you claim the bonus. But don't get too greedy, or you may lose control of the gyms you already captured.

Comment: Not only the gym gets xp, the player gets some as well.

Comment: You say "you can collect them in the shop at the right top", but I don't see it. I have some Gym that nobody cares about being defended for 14 days in a row. So I go to shop hoping to claim coins you mentioned and there's nothing at the right top. At the top there's amount of coins I currently have. If I scroll down for this to get hidden, then at the right top appears a line with the same number. Both of them are unclickable. Overall, there are various sections with goods to buy and at the bottom an entry for promo codes. But nothing like you describe.

Answer (score 22):

One point to clarify from Bluerex, is that you can get the Defenders reward (10 gold coins and 500 stardust) whether you are the gym leader or not. So far there are no extra benefits from being the gym leader except for showing off your high level Pokemon (compared to others in that gym). I guess your Pokemon in the gym has a little more security as the lower level Pokemon need to be removed before your's does.

Comment: 500 stardust for the defenders reward

Answer (score -1):

When you win a gym place and hold it, you get coins and star dust. You then use the star dust with your candy to "upgrade" your pokemon.

Comment: This answer adds nothing not covered in far more detail by the other answers. Duplicate answers are of no use to anyone and may be deleted.