# Does training increase Pokemon stats?

Tags: pokemon-go

If you train at a gym (one on the same team) you can gain experience and prestige.

But does training help the CP of the Pokemon who was battling? It would seem to make sense, but I haven't seen evidence of it happening.

Comment: duplicate of [gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274347/when-does-your-pokemon-get-cp-at-a-gym](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274347/when-does-your-pokemon-get-cp-at-a-gym)

Answer (score 8):

No.

The only way to increase the CP of a pokemon is to Power them Up using Candy and Stardust.

Battling a gym will either increase (if same team) or decrease (if other team) the prestige of the gym if you beat at least one of the pokemon stationed there.

Comment: It may be helpful to add that gym prestige decreases when it is owned by an enemy team, and increases when owned by your team.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf updated.

Comment: @waxeagle But there's so many more details than that.. you battle with 6 Pokemon when it's against an enemy and you have to revive your Pokemon vs battling with 1 Pokemon when it's against a friendly gym and your Pokemon are left at 1HP.

Comment: @waxeagle This question asked about training.. so why include details about battling when there's already much better answers on dedicated questions for it

Answer (score 3):

As Pokemon GO currently does not have EVs implemented (and CP seemingly doesn't change after training), training provides a Pokemon no advantage whatsoever.

However, training a Pokemon at a Gym will increase that Gym's prestige (and therefore level). The Prestige gains are dependent on how strong the Pokemon you're training with is compared to how strong the Gym itself is, in order to keep some semblance of balance in the game.

Comment: What's an EV? Sorry Pokemon noob

Comment: @JeremyFrench EVs are the "stats" in the traditional Pokemon games -- Speed, Attack, Defense, Sp. Attack, and so on. Niantic decided to replace these with the CP mechanic in this game, so they're not present (yet).

Comment: EVs aren't the stats themselves - Speed, Attack, Defense etc are just referred to as "Stats". EVs are the internal values (usually hidden, but appear in graph form in recent games) used to calculate stat growth on levelling up, and influenced by the "EV Yield" of the Pokémon battled (amongst other controllable factors). It's a big ol' topic: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values But yeah, the stats themselves are just Stats. (everything in this comment is referring to the main games, for clarity. Pokémon Go has neither EVs or Stats)